# Outlook add-in: Publishing and updating through VS code

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I created an Outlook add-in with a taskpane. I try to updating the extension by the same process of deploying on VS code with Azure extension and Deploy Static website to the same storage account. And then I tested. And works for me. But when my client tries it keeps the old version. I even give again the manifest.prod.xml. But it doesn't change even with the same file the results are different. Someone has an idea why?

Comment: If you ever modify the manifest, your client has to re-install it to pick up the new changes. Also, is your client using the rich Windows Desktop Outlook client, or the web-based client in a browser or Mac Outlook?

Comment: He's using both of them

Comment: When you say both, I think you are referring to Windows Desktop Outlook and the web-based client, but not Mac Outlook. Correct me if I'm wrong. If the customer re-installed the manifest, then the link to "Clear the Office cache" that Eugene Astafiev mentioned should be helpful. Also, the customer can use our debugging tools to force the add-in to load without the browser cache.

Comment: Also, are your changes in the manifest, the web content, or both?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the web browser caches files locally. Read more about that in the [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) article.

Use the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header holds directives (instructions) for caching in both requests and responses. So, you may instruct the web browser by including the required header directives to invalidate the cache each time the request is made and etc.

Comment: I've been testing how to work with blob properties. By putting: Cache-Control: no-store
I'm putting in each file of the $web container. But my client said nothing changed do you have an idea what's it? And also do you any way more effective to do this?

Comment: You need to clear the cache before deploying the very first version with the header set up. Otherwise, you would need to clear the cache manually.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? Or give link to how to this set up before deploying?

Comment: See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache)

Comment: So if I modify the manifest a little I can delete the cache of my my previous version correct?